# Why does SendKeys produce an error in Windows 7?

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, sendkeys

I am trying to run this code:

```
SendKeys "copy /b /y " & outputfile & " " & printerid & "{Enter}", 1.
```

It runs fine in Windows XP but in Windows 7 it gives an error.

I am trying to copy a string into cmd and execute it.
The "{Enter}" part is giving error.
Please help.

Comment: Are you actually writing an ASP.NET application?

Comment: This doesn't look like any ASP.NET I've ever written.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the error code/error message with us?

Answer (score 0):

A quick test on Windows 7 gives me:

```
'sendkeys' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If that's the same error that you're getting, it means you don't have the program. Try copying it over from XP and see if that works.

If you've already copied it, it might not be in your `PATH`. Try this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Path\to\SendKeys\
```

where `C:\Path\to\SendKeys` is the folder that contains SendKeys.exe.